# Update magento from 2.3.1 to 2.4.2 - sql error - on getting the products

Tags: magento2

So after updating magento from 2.3.1 to 2.4.2, went almost flawless, until i saw this error on the category page,

```
"0":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cat_index_position' in 'order clause', query was: SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, IFNULL(review_summary.reviews_count, 0) AS `reviews_count`, IFNULL(review_summary.rating_summary, 0) AS `rating_summary`, `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`\n INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 AND price_index.website_id = '1'\n LEFT JOIN `review_entity_summary` AS `review_summary` ON e.entity_id = review_summary.entity_pk_value AND review_summary.store_id = 1 AND review_summary.entity_type = (SELECT `review_entity`.`entity_id` FROM `review_entity` WHERE (entity_code = 'product'))\n INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id WHERE (e.entity_id IN (112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 170, 249, 250)) ORDER BY `cat_index_position` ASC\n","1":"
```

So im almost lost, on what to do or fix it. Anybody who has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove this line

```
ORDER BY `cat_index_position` ASC
```

from your sql query

Comment: I actually did that. I checked the old database and saw that, the column "cat_index_position" didnt exist there. So i just deleted it. But i dont understand why magneto 2.3.1 never gave an error?

Comment: With the upgraded version they(Magento) keep on upgrading the security and other improvements. Please accept it as an answer if possible.